# What is the font used on Captain Kirk's chair?

Tags: font-identification

I've tried using automated online tools (fontspring, whatthefont, fontsquirrel) for font identification but the only image I can find is at an angle so the tools don't process the image's text properly.

Might someone know what font this is on Captain Kirk's chair?

[image]

Comment: I've no clue what the font is, but you could perspective crop & try again - https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfLhx.jpg

Comment: It's rather hard to tell from this image, but it looks similar to [Alternate Gothic No. 2](https://fontsgeek.com/fonts/Alternate-Gothic-No2-Regular) ([alternatives listed here](https://www.whatfontis.com/Alternate-Gothic-No2-BT.similar?customtext=ALERT%20JETTISON%20POD))

Comment: @Tetsujin - I appreciate the suggestion. Unfortunately, the blurriness of the altered image didn't yield good results.

Comment: @r3mainer - Thanks for the suggestion. It does seem like a reasonable fit.